# Where is the link to ros::init() code API?

Tags: ros, tutorial, roscpp, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm reading this tutorial:

http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown

In this page, there is a link to "ros::init() code API", but the link is broken.
Using Google I've found another page where "ros::init()" is not a link:

http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/roscpp/html/

Could someone help me or write the correct link in the tutorial?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210432/where-is-the-link-to-ros::init()-code-api?/) by [Fabio](https://answers.ros.org/users/22620/fabio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is related to a doxygen regression: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=744762

Doxygen fails to extract the `ros::init()` functions and therefore API documentation itself can't cross reference it and the wiki can't link to them.

Until doxygen releases a fix for that we can't do anything about it.

Please look directly at the source code (https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/bd10f702dcf4c447cc421ed3fd4838f9173afe28/clients/roscpp/include/ros/init.h#L68-L103) to see the available signatures and their documentation.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2015-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1